# Running rtabmap on bag of rgb and depth images

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to run ros rtabmap on a bag of rgb and depth images, with the following topics:

```
rostopic  list
/camera/depth/camera_info
/camera/depth/image
/camera/rgb/camera_info
/camera/rgb/image_color
```

I am using the well known canned bag rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz as a reference example. This bag has the following topics:

```
rosbag info /mnt/hdd3/avnerm/avner/slam/data/rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz/rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag
...
topics:      /camera/depth/camera_info
             /camera/depth/image      
             /camera/rgb/camera_info  
             /camera/rgb/image_color  
             /cortex_marker_array     
             /imu                     
             /tf
```

In my bag I don't have /imu, /tf topics.

To get the program to flow, I added the following transforms.
I added the transform with 0 values for x,y,z,rot,pitch,yaw (i.e. no effect), except for the yaw argument to align the orientation of 3d points with the image

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="openni_rgb_optical_frame_to_world" args="0 0 0 0.0 0 -$(arg pi) /openni_rgb_optical_frame /world 100" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_to_kinect" args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /world /kinect 100" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_to_map" args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /world /map 100" />
```

If I just play my bag, I can see in rviz the images (rgb, depth) and the 3d points (via /voxel_cloud), but in local frame coordinates.
With these tf nodes the rtabmap runs, but the /rtabmap/mapData shows incorrect - the 3d points are just laid on top of each other without a proper 3d model.

I created a bag rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz_no_tf.bag without the topics: /cortex_marker_array /imu /tf, (and replaced with static transforms)

With this setting, rtabmap creates the mapData incorrectly as well.

So it looks like the launch file that I am using from [here](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/tests/rgbdslam_datasets.launch) requires the topics that were filtered above.

My questions:

- Can rtabmap handle a bag with just rgb and depth images?
- Is there an example canned bag that only uses rgb and depth images?

Thanks,

Avner

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313721/running-rtabmap-on-bag-of-rgb-and-depth-images/) by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to run ros rtabmap on a bag of rgb and depth images.

The solution was to follow the guidelines in [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/249970/will-rtab-map-work-without-tf-topic/).

I also had to run static_transform_publisher and produce the following static transformations:

- camera_link camera_depth_frame
- camera_link camera_rgb_frame
- camera_depth_frame camera_depth_optical_frame
- camera_rgb_frame camera_rgb_optical_frame
- base_link camera_link
- base_link base_scan
- world map

---

Originally posted by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) with karma: 96 on 2019-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible to map from a rosbag containing only image topics. If we break down to only minimal info from this launch file, we could have something like this with the topics you specified:

```
  <launch>
  <param name="use_sim_time" type="bool" value="True"/>
    
  <arg name="pi/2" value="1.5707963267948966" />
  <arg name="optical_rotate" value="0 0 0 -$(arg pi/2) 0 -$(arg pi/2)" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="camera_base_link"
        args="$(arg optical_rotate) base_link camera_link 100" />  
      
  <group ns="rtabmap">
  
    <!-- Odometry -->
    <node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odometry" output="screen">
      <remap from="rgb/image"       to="/camera/rgb/image_color"/>
      <remap from="depth/image"     to="/camera/depth/image"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>
      <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="base_link"/>
    </node>
    
    <!-- SLAM -->
    <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="--delete_db_on_start">
      <param name="subscribe_depth" type="bool" value="true"/>  
      <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="base_link"/>
    
      <remap from="rgb/image" to="/camera/rgb/image_color"/>
      <remap from="depth/image" to="/camera/depth/image"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>
      <remap from="odom" to="odom"/>
    </node>

  </group>
  </launch>
```

Replace `camera_link` by the frame contained in the `/camera/rgb/image_color` topic. Then play the bag:

```
$ roslaunch example_above.launch
$ rosbag play --clock recorded.bag
```

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) on 2019-02-11**:
Thanks. This helped me to find the solution to my problem (see below)